# Laravel functions :popular(), active(), ofType(), etc

Tags: php, laravel

I've just read a chapter of the Laravel 5.4 Documentation at [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

In this chapter it is described that, to define a scope, simply prefix an Eloquent model method with **scope**. In an example, two **scope**methods(scopePopular & scopeActive) were defined, and then, the following code was present, in oder to show the functionality of **scope**

```
$users = App\User::popular()->active()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

Question:

- What are the methods, popular(), active()? They don't seem like any global helper methods.
- Where can I find the documentation of these two methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Read again, specially this part: `Utilizing A Local Scope`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are local scopes. You define the `popular()` local scope like this:

```
public function scopePopular($query)
{
    return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
}
```

And then use it:

```
Model::popular()->get();
```

The documentation for [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This is why I hate Larvel+Eloquent. What is all this magic?

Comment: @agoldev I had that perspective until I did a deep dive into the Laravel world.... "It's so much easier to write straight sql!" But then I learned it and love it so much more because raw SQL is not scalable whereas Eloquent is scalable like a mutha'.

Comment: @mydoglixu Don't get me wrong. I love ORMs too. Have you worked with Doctrine at some point?

Comment: @agoldev I have, but still prefer Eloquent. To me, doctrine has a lot of explicit requirements, and it's the laravel "magic" that I have grown to love. L7 and L8 definitely do it best. When I started back in L5.3, I did prefer Doctrine.